# Bootstrap 2.x to 3.0 Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm upgrading from Bootstrap 2.x to 3.0. My home page is:  http://www.soulmd.org/index.html.

I have two issues with the new carousel:

1. I want to eliminate the gray gradient on the right, so that only the image and caption are displayed (as in the old carousel).
2. Each item is displaying ~1745px wide, far wider than my container, which is about 1140px wide.

I searched through the CSS and tried tweaking some of the parameters, but I can't figure out the specific ones for this problem.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS on fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do two things:

1) Wrap your slideshow within another div with class `.container`

2) Add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
   background: none !important;
}
```

Hope that helps!

**Update**

If you want to stretch the image in the gallery to make if full width you can add the following to your custom CSS stylesheet.

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
line-height: 1;
width: 100% !important;
}
```

However, a better way is to use images with the correct dimensions to avoid poor resolution due to image stretching.

Comment: Almost perfect.  There is still a smaller gray gradient on the right.  It's as if the image doesn't stretch the full width.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm just going to expand the slide images to cover the gray area.  But if you have a different solution, I'd love to hear it. BTW, If I could vote, you'd get mine.

Comment: You need to make sure that the image has the correct dimensions so it fits the container (in your case at least 1140px in width) because otherwise you would need to stretch the image. By the way, where did you add the custom CSS? Your links to your custom stylesheets don't seem to work.

Comment: Just updated my answer. If you think that I solved your problem it would be great if you could mark my answer as the correct solution by clicking the check mark. Thanks!